# Video hosted on IIS does not play in Web Browser

Tags: html, iis, iis-7.5, mp4

I have set up IIS on my Windows 7 PC and can access a basic HTML Web Page like so:

```
http://MY.LOCAL.IP.ADDRESS/home.html
```

Now I have created a folder:
    C:\inetpub\wwwroot\videos and copied in a small mp4 video file:

```
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\videos\test.mp4
```

I want to access this video file like so:

```
<p><a href="http://localhost/videos/test.mp4">Sample MP4 Video File 1</a></p>
<p><a href="http://127.0.0.1/videos/test.mp4">Sample MP4 Video File 2</a></p>
<p><a href="http://my.Ip.Add.ress/videos/test.mp4">Sample MP4 Video File 3</a></p>
```

But when I click on the links I get the following error:
 [image]

How can I get this video to stream?

Comment: You can find explanation from https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/943891/the-http-status-code-in-iis-7-0-iis-7-5-and-iis-8-0

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to add the .mp4 MimeType to the IIS Default WebSite like so:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If your type of video is MP4 running on IIS/.NET

Add a web.config file to the root of the application with the following contents

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <configuration>
    <system.webServer>
      <staticContent>
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".mp4" mimeType="application/mp4" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/font-woff2" />
      </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
  </configuration>
```